# How do I change swagger-ui path to open up custom documentation?

Tags: openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to document my REST API using OpenAPI 3.0 (version 1.5.0). My question is how do I change the swagger url to redirect to my custom doc?

This is my current application.yml file:

```
  api-docs:
    path: /custom/api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    path: /custom/swagger
    config-url: /custom/api-docs
```

If I then try to start my application and access the swagger documentation using this link:
https://localhost:8080/custom/swagger

I'm redirected to
https://localhost:8080/custom/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/custom/api-docs

Which opens up the Petstore documentation, not my custom one.

If I manually type in this in the URL:
https://localhost:8080/custom/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/custom/api-docs
(*change **configUrl** to **url***) it opens up my custom documentation.

Is what I want to achieve possible, that when typing https://localhost:8080/custom/swagger it opens up my  custom swagger doc, instead of the Petstore one?

If this matters, here is my dependency:

```
<!-- Springdoc for OpenAPI 3 -->
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl is not relevant for your configuration.

This is relevant is you have an external configuration file as stated in the documentation:

- https://springdoc.org/#swagger-ui-properties

Comment: I thought as much, but with or without the problem is exactly the same; so the reason why I tried to configure **configUrl** was to see if that somehow opened up my custom specification.

Even if I try something as simple as this:
`springdoc.swagger-ui.url= /custom/swagger`

I get an error message saying **No API definition provided.**.